# Conditional Expecation of a function of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, concentration-of-measure

I am trying to read about basic concentration of measure inequalities from Lugosi's lecture notes. ( [Link to pdf](http://www.econ.upf.edu/~lugosi/anu.pdf) ).

I cannot understand a step in the proof of Thm.7 (On Page 16 of the pdf)

The step that I cannot understand is the following. 
Suppose $Z= g(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$, where $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$ are independent random variables. The the author says that, it follows from the independence of $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$, that:
$ \mathbb{E}[Z| (X_j)_{j=1}^{i-1}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Z|X_{-i}]|(X_j)_{j=1}^i]$

Here $X_{-i} = (X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},\ldots,X_n)$.

It seems similar to the tower property of conditional expectation, but I cannot seem to see how it is true.

The way I think of it is that $ \mathbb{E}[Z|X_{-i}]$ is a function of $X_{-i}$, and hence independent of $X_i$, and thus the conditioning it on $(X_j)_{j=1}^i$ is the same as conditioning it on $(X_j)_{j=1}^{i-1}$. But how do I show it rigorously?

Comment: Considering $U=(X_j)_{j\leqslant i-1}$, $V=X_i$, $W=(X_j)_{j\geqslant i+1}$, the problam is to show that, for independent $(U,V,W)$ and every $g$, one has $$E(g(U,V,W)\mid U)=E(E(g(U,V,W)\mid U,W)\mid U,V),$$
that is, that, for every $h$, one has $$E(h(U,W)\mid U,V)=E(h(U,W)\mid U).$$ The reason why this holds true is that $W$ is independent of $(U,V)$ hence $$E(h(U,W)\mid U,V)=f(U),$$ wirh $$f(u)=E(h(u,W)).$$

Comment: @Did Thanks. Writing it out like this makes it clear to me.